# How to change type of nested field in BigQuery via CAST?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a new table from a query, casting one of the nested fields on the way.
Something like that:

```
#standardSQL    
SELECT * EXCEPT (bid_info),
  (SELECT AS STRUCT bid_info.* EXCEPT (clicks), CAST(bid_info.clicks AS NUMERIC) as clicks 
  FROM `testing.fb_ads.ads`) as bid_info
FROM `testing.fb_ads.ads`
```

I am getting error "Scalar subquery produced more than one element" and the query execution doesn't seem to end.

How can I fix this query?

Comment: Can you run the inner query and provide the result it's producing. I assume by looking at the result and BigQuery error message we can find the issue

Comment: Thanks @TamirKlein, indeed careful breaking it down lead me to a solution.

Answer (score 6):

So, I've found the solution after all, here it goes:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (bid_info),
(SELECT AS STRUCT bid_info.* EXCEPT (clicks), CAST(bid_info.clicks AS NUMERIC) as clicks ) as bid_info
FROM `testing.fb_ads.ads`
```